# How to solve this docker-compose upgrading error?

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to upgrade docker-compose from

docker-compose version 1.5.2, build unknown

To docker-compose above 1.7.x using this [Upgrading instructions](http://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) (Under Upgrading section).

Upgrade instruction followed:

- **docker-compose migrate-to-labels**

I get following error

**- ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.**

The docker-compose.yml file I am using is

```
version: '2'
services:
    dockerapp:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
    redis:
        image: redis:3.2.0
```

Comment: Still no luck?...

Comment: I left the project because many technologies in it were deprecated already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install directly a newer version using curl. For example:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Note that I've specified /usr/bin/docker-compose destination and normally, when you install via apt-get, docker-compose is installed in /usr/local/bin
Assure that you're using correct version with

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.20.0-rc2, build 8c4af54
```

After that, upgrade your docker-compose file version according to: [(see)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources)